# Как передать массив input через ajax в обработчик php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Есть инпут типа :

```
<input type="email" class="form__field" name="login_form[username]"  value="email" required />
<input type="pass" class="form__field"  name="login_form[password]"  value="email" required />
```

Обработчик принимает : 
    utils::validate_user_data( $_POST['login_form'] );
Мне нужно этот массив через Ajax передать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте передать сразу данные формы с помощью объекта `FormData`:

```
    var data = new FormData($('#idForm')[0]);
    var url = 'your url'
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function(response) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

        },
        complete: function () {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('login_form[username]','username');
data.append('login_form[username]','username');
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        data: data,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('submit', '#form', function(){
   var data = $(this).serializeArray(); // этот метод соберет все поля формы даже массивы из импутов
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'url',
      data: data,
      success : function(respons){
         console.log(respons);
      }
   });
});
```